# Multiple update statements vs Single Update/Merge statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-update, sql-merge

I have a Unix Shell script that processes a flat file line by line using 'awk' command and updates an Oracle database table. It does this by printing an Update command for each line and piping it to an file like so -

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; cnt=0;} {print "update Employee set hours=hours+"$6*(1)" 
where ID="$3" and LastName="$4";"; cnt=cnt+1; if(cnt%100==0) print "commit;"; }' 
$DATA_PATH/$DATETIME/$filename | sed s/@/\'/g > $SYNC_PATH//$DATETIME/$filename
```

The file is then run using SQLPLUS as below -

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus admin/pass@word1  @$SYNC_PATH/$DATETIME/$filename

Update: I am migrating all of this to a Windows Server 2012\Sql Server 2012\SSIS environment.

I want to convert this process into an SSIS package. I have two options -

- Replicate the same logic in SSIS as above i.e. read from the flat file line bye line and create a '.sql' file containing update statements that I can run using an "Execute SQL task"
- Bulk insert from the flat file into a Staging table on the DB and use an Update/Join or Merge statement to update my Target table.

Which one is the better option? Are both these methods functionally the same in the sense that the data in the target table is the same after both operations complete.

Comment: Bulk Insert / Staging/ Merge gives you more control over processing the import in SQL although you may be more comfortable with AWK. Staging. it will set up for more sophisticated processing for example if you need to clean the data in the staging table based on other tables, you can do this efficiently with a bunch of UPDATE statements. Can you imagine writing an AWK script that has to go look up values in a database then update the file. You can also include more sophisticated error handler, transactions etc. If this process is going to get any more complex you should go the bulk insert

Comment: Keep in mind that you can builk insert/merge without SSIS and sometimes this is easier because you don't have to fight the SSIS infrastructure / learning curve.